# first data won't insert into bigquery table

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I'm trying to insert large dataset into bigquery table but I discovered that first package of data don't insert to the bq via stream.
Then I have tried with single line data but I saw that still same.

```
data = ["u", "u", "u"]
package = [data]
while True:
try:

    table.reload()
    errors = table.insert_data(package)
    break
except:
    print("hata")
print(errors)
```

If I run this code multiple times, then it inserts for nrun -1 times.

For example if I run this code 4 times it adds 3 times.
If I run this code one time, it doesn't add anything.

Comment: I'm wondering how do you check that the data wasn't inserted? Did you do a SELECT * and only saw 3 rows or did you use something else.

Comment: I did select * from table and saw nothing.

Comment: Is it possible to update your answer to have a more complete code that reproduces the issue? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are other factors like the table schema, was the table created beforehand or is it recreated every time. If I have to guess, you wrote `data = ["u", "u", "u"]` which means that 3 rows inserted at a time, each with a single value of "u", not 1 rows with 3 columns.